# Can I import .csv files based on a partial filename?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

So the data that I need to work with comes as a set of 10 .csv files each with names of the following format:

Example_datatype_date_IDnumber.csv

Each of the 10 files requires different manipulation/analysis and I'd like to do it all with one python script. I can do it successfully with pandas but the issue is that every time I get a new set I have to go in and manually change the date and ID number in the filename when I import the file. Is there a way to import the files and ignore the date and ID number (differentiate only based on datatype)? I would just create a new folder/directory for each set of 10.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. Providing examples might help. But you might want to look into the glob library.

Answer (score 1):

If you put all files in one folder (assume c:\tmp), you could use regex and `glob` to find all files:

```
import glob 
path = r"c:\\tmp\\*.csv"
for filePath in glob.glob(path):
    # read file and analysis file
```

or

```
import re
import os
pattern  = r'\w+_\w+_\w+_\w+\.csv'
for i in os.listdir("c:\\tmp\\"):
  if re.search(pattern,i):
    # read file and analysis file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to detect the datatype from the file name:

```
import os, re

files = os.listdir("my_directory")

for fname in files:
    m = re.search('[^_]+_([^_]+).*\csv', fname)
    if m:
        datatype = m.group(1)
        print fname
        print datatype
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, re

path_containing_csv_files = '/tmp/test' #contains < example_int_12-12-16_1.csv, example_string_11-12-16_2.csv>

def process_int(filepath):
    #process int data here
    pass

def process_string(filepath):
    #process string data here
    pass

methods = {'int':process_int,
           'string':process_string}

for file_name in os.listdir(path_containing_csv_files):
    parsed = re.search('[^_]+_([^_]+).*\csv', file_name))
    if parsed:
        methods[parsed.group(1)](os.path.join(path_containing_csv_files, file_name))
```